Entity Framework does not consider applied migrations
I recently started to work on a .NET project using Entity Framework (5.0.11). This project already has 5 registered migrations, and after creating a new model (+ register it to DbContext), I generated a new migration.
Here is my new model class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Myproject.Database
{
    public class CompanyData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Company Company{ get; set; }
        public int CustomDataId { get; set; }
    }
}

And here is the migration created when I run
dotnet ef migrations add M6

public partial class M6 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CompanyDatas",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                CompanyId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                CustomDataId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_CompanyData", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_CompanyDatas_tCompany_CompanyId",
                    column: x => x.CompanyId,
                    principalTable: "tCompany",
                    principalColumn: "com_id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_CompanyDatas_CompanyId",
            table: "CompanyDatas",
            column: "CompanyId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "CompanyDatas");
    }
}

The migration file seems to be good, since it reflects the changes I've made when creating my model.
However, when I run dotnet ef database update to update my database, Entity Framework tries to execute all the migrations from the beginning.
After checking in my database, I could see that there are the following registered migrations.
MigrationId         ProductVersion
----------------------------------
20240219103430_M1   5.0.11
20240219105713_M2   5.0.11
20240305074220_M3   5.0.11
20240311150824_M4   5.0.11
20240319153547_M5   5.0.11

But when I run dotnet ef migrations list --verbose, the terminal outputs the following information :
20240219103430_M1 (Pending)
20240219105713_M2 (Pending)
20240305074220_M3 (Pending)
20240311150824_M4 (Pending)
20240319153547_M5 (Pending)
20240925150433_M6 (Pending)

I don't understand why M1 to M5 migrations appear as pending since they are in the [__EFMigrationsHistory] table.
Thank you in advance for any help.
